# How can I make a CSS background that is all white with a 100px blue bar at the very top of the page?

Tags: css

I see a lot of code dealing with percentages, but what if I just wanted a 100px bar in the top? I am only able to edit the CSS of this page, so can I do it without any use of HTML?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `:before` pseudo-element:

```
body:before {
    content: " ";
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}
```

With this you can change some properties and have this results:

#### Content Above the Bar

```css
body {
  color:white;
  margin:0;
}
body:before {
    content: " ";
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
    z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<h1>The content will be above the bar</h1>
```

#### Content Under the Bar

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}
body:before {
    content: " ";
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<h1>The content will be under the bar</h1>
```

Comment: @Danko `width:100%` is not needed if `display:block` is set on the pseudo element.  Also, if you do decide to position the pseudo element absolutely, you do not need `display:block`.

Comment: good answer. note that as of CSS3, pseudo-elements such as `::before` should begin with two colons in order to differentiate them from pseudo-classes, although the one-colon syntax is still supported.

Comment: @Danko there's still a strong argument in favor of the one-colon syntax (namely, there's no guarantee that legacy browsers will support the two-colon syntax, whereas current browsers are still supporting the one-colon syntax), but since we are in an era of transition, i believe it is an important thing to note. [Here is a source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements#Notes), including browser support, if you're curious.

Comment: Thanks I will check that later @WoodrowBarlow

Answer (score 3):

You can use a sized, laterally-repeating, linear-gradient:

```
html {
    background: white linear-gradient( 0, blue, blue ) repeat-x;
    background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/r5a2uabw/4/

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, simply use a `border-top` on the `body`.

```
body {
    border-top: 100px solid blue;
    margin: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n8mq9prr/

Answer (score 1):

I am not in front of a computer where I can try this right now, but it seems like you should be able to set the background color to white and then load a 100 pixel tall background image of your desired shade of blue and set the image to repeat in the x-direction (horizontally) but not the y direction

Answer (score 1):

Add a border-top to your body. Than possibly pad your content accordingly.

Something possibly like this.

```
body {
     border-top: 100px solid blue;
}
```

If you had any examples we could help in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Put this HTML at the very top of your page. First piece of code blow `<body>`

```
<div id="topBar"></div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
#topBar {
    height:100px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    }
```

Comment: Did you read the question? "so can I do it without any use of HTML".

Comment: Danko is taking advantage of CSS3, which is awesome. Good answer. Both work, but his is using CSS3 where as mine is using CSS2.

Comment: Woops, that's my mistake. Danko's answer is much better. Sorry about that.

Comment: Correction: `:before` and `:after` [are part of CSS 2.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `::before` pseudo class on the `<body>` element, or another top-level container.

```
body::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jmvu4v6f/)